Angular app deployed behind ingress controller returns invalid mime type
I am trying to deploy an angular application in my local minikube cluster, behind a ingress controller. I am using the builtin nginx ingress controller.
When I try to access the correspoding path to the web spa service I get error in the console
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
However when I access the service directly using kubectl port forward I can access the app correctly
These are my deployment, services and ingress resources
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-spa-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web-spa
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web-spa
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web-spa
        image: phadkesharanmatrixcomsec/iva-workflow:web-spa-2.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
          value: "Production"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-spa-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: web-spa
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: ClusterIP


apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "http://localhost:4200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "Authorization, Content-Type"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: hostname.local
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: web-spa-service
                port:
                  number: 80

Also this is my dockerfile where I build the nginx image
# Stage 1: Build the Angular application
FROM node:18 AS build

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY src/WebSPA/package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the Angular application source code
COPY src/WebSPA ./

# Build the Angular application
RUN npm run build --prod

# Stage 2: Serve the Angular application
FROM nginx:alpine

# Copy built Angular application from the previous stage
COPY --from=build /app/dist/web-spa/browser /usr/share/nginx/html

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Start Nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

I have already tried different path types : Prefix / ImplementationSpecific, and also tried disabling CORS.
Also I am able to easily deploy backend api endpoints, with the same ingress resource, I am facing this issue only with the frontend
Again I am able to access the same frontend application by port-forwarding
kubectl port-forward svc/web-spa-service 8080:80
Also there is no issue with acceesing hostname.local as I have created a dns entry in /etc/hosts
Please help.

Solution is simple remove this from annotation in ingress yaml file
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1

or if you maintainte the rewrite-target you must add path like this : /(.*)
